# How does perception work?

Tags: pillars-of-eternity

I play path of damned difficulty and have just got the fifth party member. I feel like the biggest problem is lack of accuracy: every swing, ability or spell has a very high rate to miss or graze, and this often leads to a wipe or a knock out. Most of my characters have accuracy around 25-45, however I have seen mobs with all 4 defense at around 80ish, even with all buffs from food, rest and spells on it's very hard to actually carry out a strategy which relies on a certain hit rate of abilities. I think there must be a certain accuracy threshold that you have to reach, otherwise your team build won't be legit.

If I get it right, perception is the main source of accuracy, so why isn't it the most important attribute for most classes? Why would a DPS need might if 1 out of 2 hits is missing? And I read an article saying perception is mainly for defense, why is that?

Answer (score 4):

The reason perception is not that important, is that it only grants +1 to accuracy per point above 10. Whether your characters sport 30 or 35 accuracy (assuming 15 perception) doesn't make much of a difference, the 15% dmg increase from might or 15% atk speed increase from dex have a far bigger impact.

You are correct though, that accuracy is the biggest problem on higher difficulties, however perception is not the way to get it. You still should have a character with very high perception (18+) to detect secrets and traps. (note: this only applies to PoE 2, in the first game, mechanics skill is used to detect secrets and traps.)

[The wiki](https://pillarsofeternity.gamepedia.com/Accuracy) has a comprehensive list of accuracy sources. Here are some tips:

- use accuracy bonus weapons and specialize on them (spear, rapier, dagger or club)
- wield single one-handed weapons without a shield. If you use a rapier without a shield and specialized in the weapon type, this adds a whopping +23 to your accuracy.
- possibly: use accurate 2 weapons (+8), instead of fine (+4, but higher dmg).
- Paladin aura (+6)
- use accuracy gauntlets
- Priest abilities: +5 from blessing spell (lvl 1), holy radiance with inspire talent (+10), devotions of the faithful (+20, lvl 7)

Finally, reducing the opponents defenses is also very important: ciphers are very good at that. [List of afflictions](https://pillarsofeternity.gamepedia.com/Status_effects#Afflictions). Prone, blind, stuck, weakened, stunned, paralyzed, charmed are all available pretty early and debuff the enemy significantly.

Answer (score -1):

Perception is one of the skills that increases the accuracy of the character:

From the [wiki](https://pillarsofeternity.gamepedia.com/Perception)

> Perception represents a character's senses as well as their instinctive ability to pick up on details. In interactions, it can be used to catch someone in a lie, to make an observant comment about their appearance, or to notice something happening in the background. In combat, it contributes to the accuracy, Reflex defenses and grants a bonus to Interrupt.

There is also a more detailed description on how it increases Accuracy:

> Per point of Perception above/below 10, a character gains:
>   ±2 to their Reflex defense.
>   ±3 to the Interrupt potential of their attacks.
>   ±1 to the Accuracy of their attacks.

For how to increase your accuracy:

> Accuracy is part of the combat game mechanics in Pillars of Eternity. It is counted against the target's appropriate defenses and determines the likeliness of Hits and Crits or Grazes and Misses, thus influencing the success of an attack.
>   A character's actual Accuracy depends on a number of factors: primarily on their class and level, but also their Perception, Abilities and Talents, the weapon and other equipment, the situation, and more.

If you want more information about accuracy be sure to check out the [wiki](https://pillarsofeternity.gamepedia.com/Perception)